# Bold or strong tag is not working in android 14(After applying typeface)(with both Html and HtmlCompat)

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, bold, html.fromhtml

**Bold tag is not working in android 14(After applying typeface)(with both Html or HtmlCompat)**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            textview.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                getString(R.string.textWithBold)/*response.optString("title")*/,
                HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY,
                null,
                HtmlTagHandler()
            ).toString()
        } else {
            textview.text = Html.fromHtml("<b>Hey</b> How r u"/*response.optString("title")*/).toString()
        }
```

Need a solution without Spannable bold.(Because tag related content getting from backend side)

Answer (score 0):

u can use style

```
"<p><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Hey</span> How are you?</p>"
```

or strong

```
"<p><strong>Hey</strong> How are you?</p>"
```